# Expected Value in Lottery Game

Tags: statistics

In a lottery game, a person selects a three digit number. If the person plays for \$1, he can win \$500 . Find the expectation.

In the same lottery, if a person boxes a number , he will win \$80. Find the expectation if the number $123$ is played for \$1 and is boxed.

(Boxed meaning in any order- $123$, $321$, $213$, $312$, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

There are 1000 equally likely numbers from $0$ to $999$.

In the first part only one of those numbers will give a win.
Expected win $=-1\cdot \cfrac{999}{1000} + 500 \cdot \cfrac{1}{1000}$.

In the second part there are 6 possible conbinations of $123$ that can give a win
Expected win $= -1 \cdot \cfrac{994}{1000} + 80 \cdot \cfrac{6}{1000}$.

Comment: I suspect the $-1$ needs to be multiplied by $\dfrac{1000}{1000}$ as most lotteries do not refund the stake to prize winners